# Installing Flash on Steam with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, flash, steam

I recently installed Steam on my Windows 8 desktop and the Flash content won't show up. I never had to install Flash separately for Steam so I wonder what's going on. I follow the usual instructions to install Flash but it installs it on my browser not on the application. Since all my browsers already have Flash installed, how can I install Flash on Steam under Windows 8?

Comment: Steam uses an own browser based on [Webkit](http://www.webkit.org/). It's unlikely that they included Flash (or any other plugin) support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam doesn't have a built in Flash player like Google Chrome does. It uses Adobe Flash player from your computer. In order Steam to display Flash content you must download it from Adobe's website: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: I also had to restart Steam after my installation finished

Answer (score 3):

When trying to view some content through Steam, if you don't have the Flash Player that Steam requires, you will get the following message:

> You need to have a specific Flash Player installed to view video content in Steam. Please follow these directions to get the right version for Steam.
>
> You will need this Flash player even if you already have the latest player for your default web browser.

Clicking on "these directions" displays Steam's official instructions:
[image: Flash Player instructions from Steam]

When following those instructions and navigating to  http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions there is no option to select Windows 8 for your operating system:
[image: No Windows 8 option]

The solution is to select yoru operating system as: Windows 7/Vista/XP/2008/2003.
Then select your version as "Flash Player 11 for Other Browsers".
(Remember uncheck the McAfee Security Scan Plus box if you don't want that optional extra.)

You should now see this:
[image: You should see this before downloading]

Download the file (install_flashplayer11x32_mssd_aih.exe).
Run the file (recommend allowing flash updates for security reasons).
Restart Steam.
Success!

Comment: It didn't work for me. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [link](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions). Choose Windows 7/Vista/XP/2008/2003 and Flash Player for other browsers. Go to steam, if it is open already close it (Steam, Exit). Once closed, open it back up and you should be all set. It worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The IMHO best way to get Adobe Flash is through the [distribution downloads page](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html). Doesn’t contain any unwanted additions and is a full installer (not web-based).

Steam (and Firefox and whatnot) wants the version for “plugin-based browsers”.

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to install flash for steam, you have to install flash for browser(like IE) and steam automatically hook it

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue.  Turns out IE in Windows 8 comes with Flash already installed and turned on, but this is not enough.  Here's what I did to fix it:

1. Go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
2. Under Step 1 drop-down select Windows 7/Vista/XP/2008/2003. (Yes even if you have Win 8)
3. Under Step 2 drop-down select Flash Player X for Other Browsers.
4. Run the install program.
5. Restart Steam.

These directions are altered from thie following source:
http://store.steampowered.com/gotflash

Comment: Downvoted after an over zealous edit.